# Recursively Method in Prevent Iteration

Tags: c#, recursion, methods

I have a sql database and entered into any table name with i am cretae table hiyerarchy as follows segments.

Z A B C D E F is a Table Name and Z in have A foreign ID. A in have B foreign ID. But when F table in have D or Z ID Name. This Recursively Method Not Stop.

How I detected Table children in have itself.

```
Z
  A
    B
      C=> The continuation of here if comes Z or A or B ID Method not stop and call itself.
  D
    E
    F=> The continuation of here if comes D or Z ID Method not stop and call itself.
     D
     Z
```

Comment: Pass a list of visited tables to the method and check whether the new table you're about to visit is in the list.

Comment: How i am doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of the method proposed in the comment above...

```
void RecursiveMethod( Table table, List<string> visitedTables )
{
    // note the currently visited table
    var extendedList = visitedTables.ToList();
    extendedList.Add( table.Name );

    // do your thing with the table...

    // ... and recurse deeper
    foreach (var referencedTable in table.ReferencedTables)
        if (!visitedTables.Contains( referencedTable.Name ))
            RecursiveMethod( referencedTable, extendedList );
}
```

Then start with something like

```
RecursiveMethod( theRootTable, new List<string>() );
```

Comment: Thanx I try this after 4 hours.